# get a reference to an embedded mongoid object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoid model with an embedded list of items

```
Class Menu
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :code

  has_many :items
end

Class Item
  field :name
end
```

I am trying to append to model.items while retaining a reference to the item in a class variable

however i seem to be getting a clone instead?

how do i accomplish this

```
    13: def run(model)
    14:   model.items << object
    15:   binding.pry
 => 16:   @object = model.order_items.last
    17:   model
    18: end

> object.id
=> BSON::ObjectId('595a912b8f337c6da0d764db')
> model.order_items.first.id
=> BSON::ObjectId('595a91268f337c6da0d764da')
> foo = model.order_items.last
> foo.id
=> BSON::ObjectId('595a91268f337c6da0d764da')    <-- ok expected
> @object = foo
> object.id
=> BSON::ObjectId('595a91718f337c6da0d764dc')   <--wtf?
> @object.id
=> BSON::ObjectId('595a91718f337c6da0d764dc')   <-- double wtf?
Add Commententer code here
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here and to what means.

Comment: I'm trying to track an item object which is a relation of model.  but i keep getting different item.id